# Iconify React with Eva icons showing typescript error

Tags: reactjs, react-icons

I'm getting this issue:

> Property 'fr' is missing in type '{ icon: IconifyIcon; }' but required in type 'Pick<IconProps, "string" | "children" | "className" | "style" | "display" | "overflow" | "visibility" | "order" | "color" | "width" | "height" | "fontFamily" | "fontSize" | ... 465 more ... | "vAlign">'.  TS2741 (Typescript)

These are the packages that I've been using:

```
"@iconify/icons-eva": "^1.1.0"
"@iconify/icons-ic": "^1.1.15"
"@iconify/react": "^3.1.0"
```

And here is the sample code:

```js
import { Icon } from '@iconify/react';
import plusFill from '@iconify/icons-eva/plus-fill';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Icon icon={plusFill} />
  )
}
```

Comment: I also saw this start to happen when upgrading from React 16.8.1 to React 17.0.2. Upgrading TypeScript from `4.4.2` to `4.5.4` did not fix it. `fr` comes from `@types/react`'s `SVGAttributes`. No clue why it's uniquely being marked as required...